# How to use controller actions with long names?

Tags: magento-1.7, controllers, action, name

I've created a custom module. In controller file the function as bellows.

```
    /**
     * Load slider images
     */
    public function loadImageAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

layout handler declaration is as follows.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <slider_slider_loadImage>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="slider/load" name="load_custom_slider" template="slider/slider.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </slider_slider_loadImage>
 </layout>
```

But this doesn't loads the template file. If I rename the controller action as `loadimageAction(){ ...}` then it's working.

Can anyone explain how can I use action names with several words?

```
Eg: loadImageAction()
navNextAction()
```

Any clarification on this will be appreciated.

Comment: check for the classname in the page itself, i have a feeling it should be slider_slider_loadimage instead of loadImage in the layout file. You can see what you have to use in the body class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked.

Controller action is as below.

```
  /**
     * Load slider images
     */
    public function loadImageAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

layout.xml file

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <slider_slider_loadimage>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="slider/load" name="load_custom_slider" template="slider/slider.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </slider_slider_loadimage>
 </layout>
```

The issue was earlier handler was `slider_slider_loadImage`. I changed it to `slider_slider_loadimage` . Now it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't discriminate between action names with multiple words, as far as I know.

You can look at the code in Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.

Many Magento modules have action names that are more than one word, and they don't do anything funny to take care of it. See Mage_Cms, for example.

I'm afraid your error is somewhere else.